# How to define the first column before import and bind ( rbindlist ) in R

Tags: r, rbindlist

## Goal

import and bind a list of xlsx file with unpredicted irrelevant first column.
    (Have to eliminate it but you don't know which file contains irrelevant first column.)

```
# sample : remind that the xlsx file originally don't have any column names

    DT1 = data.table(a = c("TYPE","X","Y","Z"), b = c("MONTH","Jan","Feb","Mar"))
    DT2 = data.table(a = c(NA,NA,NA,"random_irrelevant_vale") ,b = c("TYPE","X","Y","W"), c = c("MONTH","Apr","Feb","May"))

# give "idcol" & col_names = FALSE is a must
    PATH_LIST<- list.files(path = "PATH",
                               pattern = "*.xlsx",full.names = TRUE)
    names(PATH_LIST) <- basename(PATH_LIST)

    rbindlist(lapply(PATH_LIST,import,col_names = FALSE,
                             col_types = "text"),
                      idcol = "source",fill = TRUE) 

    # EXPECTED OUTPUT
    TYPE MONTH
    X    Jan
    Y    Feb
    Z    Mar
    X    Apr
    Y    Feb
    W    May
```

- Cannot simply use !grepl("random_irrevelevant_value",x) as "random_irrevelevant_value" is a random value .

How can i achieve this between the step of import and rbind them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the relevant columns are at the back and there are some files with no irrelevant columns, you can try something like:

```
DTls <- lapply(list.files(pattern="DT(.*).csv"), fread, header=FALSE)
m <- min(lengths(DTls))
rbindlist(
    lapply(DTls, function(DT) {
        cols <- head(names(DT), length(DT)-m)
        if (length(cols) > 0)
            DT[, (cols) := NULL]
        DT
    })
)
```

output:

```
     V1    V2
1: TYPE MONTH
2:    X   Jan
3:    Y   Feb
4:    Z   Mar
5: TYPE MONTH
6:    X   Apr
7:    Y   Feb
8:    W   May
```

data files:

```
library(data.table)
DT1 = data.table(a = c("TYPE","X","Y","Z"), b = c("MONTH","Jan","Feb","Mar"))
DT2 = data.table(a = c(NA,NA,NA,"random_irrelevant_vale") ,b = c("TYPE","X","Y","W"), c = c("MONTH","Apr","Feb","May"))
fwrite(DT1, "DT1.csv", col.names=FALSE)
fwrite(DT2, "DT2.csv", col.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: chinsoon12 , thankyou its a good idea and my sample ,description wasn't good enough to tell the file actually don't contain any colnames , so the first method of "header = TRUE" won't work. real data doesn't contain any clear colname like : "TYPE", "MONTH"....

Comment: yes, sometimes contain 1 irrelevant column, sometimes 2 irrelevant column. So column contains : "X","Y",e.t.c. will be the sign of the real first column.

Comment: yes, always at the back, and all files always have relevant columns. Only thing we don't know is where would the first column be appeared .

Comment: Similar least number of columns are existing but NOT fixed number ,e.g. sometimes irrelevant col = 0 + relevant col = 10 , sometimes irrelevant col = 1 + relevant col = 12  . So , the script has to be detect the first column , then get all the column until the end of columns.

Comment: @rane, i tried another version. you can see if it works